# Apache Flink: Correctly make async webservice calls within MapReduce()

Tags: java, apache-flink

I've a program with the following `mapPartition` function:

```
public void mapPartition(Iterable<Tuple> values, Collector<Tuple2<Integer, String>> out)
```

I collect batches of 100 from the inputted `values` & send them to a web-service for conversion. The result I add back to the `out` collection.

In order to speed up the process, I made the web-service calls `async` through the use of `Executors`. This created issues, either I get the [taskManager released exception](https://flink.apache.org/faq.html#the-slot-allocated-for-my-task-manager-has-been-released-what-should-i-do), or `AskTimeoutException`. I increased memory & timeouts, but it didn't help. There's quite a lot of input data. I believe this resulted in a lot of jobs being queued up with `ExecutorService` & hence taking up lots of memory.

What would be the best approach for this?

I was also looking at the taskManager vs taskSlot configuration, but got a little confused on the differences between the two (I guess they're similar to process vs threads?). Wasn't sure at what point do I increase the taskManagers vs taskSlots? e.g. if I've got three machines with 4cpus per machine, so then should my `taskManager=3` while my `taskSlot=4`?

I was also considering increasing the `mapPartition`'s parallelism alone to say `10` to get more threads hitting the web-service. Comments or suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check out [Flink Asyncio](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/stream/asyncio.html) which would enable you to query your webservice in an asynchronous way in your streaming application.

One thing to note is that the Asyncio function is not called multithreaded and is called once per record per partition sequentially, so your web application needs to deterministically return and potentially return fast for the job to not being held up.

Also, potentially higher number of partitions would help your case but again your webservice needs to fulfil those requests fast enough

Sample code block from Flinks Website:

```
// This example implements the asynchronous request and callback with Futures that have the
// interface of Java 8's futures (which is the same one followed by Flink's Future)

/**
 * An implementation of the 'AsyncFunction' that sends requests and sets the callback.
 */
class AsyncDatabaseRequest extends RichAsyncFunction<String, Tuple2<String, String>> {

/** The database specific client that can issue concurrent requests with callbacks */
private transient DatabaseClient client;

@Override
public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
    client = new DatabaseClient(host, post, credentials);
}

@Override
public void close() throws Exception {
    client.close();
}

@Override
public void asyncInvoke(final String str, final AsyncCollector<Tuple2<String, String>> asyncCollector) throws Exception {

    // issue the asynchronous request, receive a future for result
    Future<String> resultFuture = client.query(str);

    // set the callback to be executed once the request by the client is complete
    // the callback simply forwards the result to the collector
    resultFuture.thenAccept( (String result) -> {

        asyncCollector.collect(Collections.singleton(new Tuple2<>(str, result)));

    });
  }
}

// create the original stream (In your case the stream you are mappartitioning)
DataStream<String> stream = ...;

// apply the async I/O transformation
DataStream<Tuple2<String, String>> resultStream =
AsyncDataStream.unorderedWait(stream, new AsyncDatabaseRequest(), 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, 100);
```

Edit:

As the user wants to create batches of size 100 and asyncio is specific to Streaming API for the moment, thus the best way would be to create countwindows with size 100.

Also, to purge the last window which might not have 100 events, custom [Triggers](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/windows.html#triggers) could be used with a combination of Count Triggers and Time Based Triggers such that the trigger fires after a count of elements or after every few minutes.

A good follow up is available here on [Flink Mailing List](http://apache-flink-user-mailing-list-archive.2336050.n4.nabble.com/Count-windows-missing-last-elements-td6271.html#a6303) where the user "Kostya" created a custom trigger which is available [here](https://gist.github.com/krolen/ed1344e4d7be5b2116061685268651f5)

Comment: Unfortunately this is in the Streaming Api. I'm using the Batch Api. I need to collect the items into batches of 100 - don't see a way to do that transformation in the Streaming Api.

Comment: why dont you create a count window where your count size is 100 and work on that? More information here: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/datastream/KeyedStream.html#countWindow-long-

Comment: One last question - as I collect batches of 100, the last batch will have the left over elements (which will be less than 100). How can I fire the window for that?

Comment: Updated the answer, with links to use case which is something similar to yours. Hopefully you can make it work with this.

Comment: Thanks, was able to work with this. Really appreciate your coming back & helping like this.