# Apache Flink - Refresh a Hashmap asynchronously

Tags: scala, apache-flink

I am developing a Apache Flink application using Scala API ( I am pretty new using this technology).

I am using a hashmap to store some values that come from a database, and I need to refresh these values each 1h. There is any way to refresh this hashmap asynchronously?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "refresh this hashmap asynchronously" in the context of a Flink workflow.

For what it's worth, if you have a hashmap that's keyed by some piece of data from records flowing through your workflow, then you can use Flink's support for [managed key state](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/dev/stream/state/state.html#using-managed-keyed-state) to store the value (and checkpoint it), and make it [queryable](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/state/queryable_state.html).

Answer (score 0):

I interpret your question to mean that you are using some state in Flink to mirror/cache some data that comes from an external database, and you wish to periodically refresh it.

Typically this sort of thing is done by continuously streaming a Change Data Capture (CDC) stream from the external database into Flink. Continuous, streaming solutions are generally a better fit for Flink. But if you want to do this in hourly batches, you could write a custom source or a ProcessFunction that wakes up once an hour, makes a query to the database, and emits a stream of records that can be used to update the operator holding the state.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this with the use of Apache Flink's Asynchronous I/O for External Data Access, see this post for details [async io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46659043/apache-flink-correctly-make-async-webservice-calls-within-mapreduce).

Here's a way to use AsyncDataStream to refresh a map periodically by creating a async function and attaching it to a source stream.

```scala
class AsyncEnricherFunction extends RichAsyncFunction[String, (String String)] {
  @transient private var m: Map[String, String] = _
  @transient private var client: DataBaseClient = _
  @transient private var refreshInterval: Int = _

@throws(classOf[Exception])
  override def open(parameters: Configuration): Unit = {
    client = new DataBaseClient(host, port, credentials)
    refreshInterval = 1000
    load()
  }

  private def load(): Unit = {
    val str = "select key, value from KeyValue"
    m = client.query(str).asMap    
    lastRefreshed = System.currentTimeMillis()
  }

 override def asyncInvoke(input: String, resultFuture: ResultFuture[(String, String]): Unit = {
    Future {
      if (System.currentTimeMillis() > lastRefreshed + refreshInterval) load()      
      val enriched = (input, m(input))
      resultFuture.complete(Seq(enriched))
    }(ExecutionContext.global)
  }

  override def close() : Unit = { client.close() }
}

 val in: DataStream[String] = env.addSource(src)
 val enriched = AsyncDataStream.unorderedWait(in, AsyncEnricherFunction(), 5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, 100)
```

Comment: Do not post a link to a tool or library as an answer. Demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself. Do [edit] the answer, and flag for undeletion once you have added the demonstration.